# Deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' c++

Tags: c++

```
class employee {
        public :
            employee (char *inName, char *inPosition, double inSalary =0.0);
            ~employee();
            char getName()const;
            char getPosition()const;
            double getSalary()const;
            virtual void display();
        private :
            char name[40];
            char position[40];
            double salary;
        protected:
            void setName(char inName);
            void setPosition(char inPosition);
            void setSalary(double inSalary);
};
employee::employee(char *inName, char *inPosition, double inSalary){
    setName(*inName);
    setPosition(*inPosition);
    setSalary(inSalary);
}
//destructor
//setter
//getter
void employee::display(){
    cout<<"Employee Name Is     :"<<getName()<<endl;
    cout<<"Employee Position Is :"<<getPosition()<<endl;
    cout<<"Employee Salary  :"<<getSalary()<<endl;
}
int main{
    char *x ="bello";
    employee e1(x, "123",50);
    e1.display();
}
```

How could i possibly solve this problem as in my employee e1(x, "123",50),
I have receive a message of: Deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*. What is the possible solution?

Comment: Most of your code is irrelevant. You could reproduce this in three lines of code.

Comment: The message is pretty clear. The conversion from a string constant to `char*` is deprecated, so don't convert a string constant to `char*`.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be but inserting  employee e1("bello", "123",50) does not give me any output as well. Any correct format?

Comment: Prefer `std::string` over `char*`.

Comment: @Synetrix Because you have the same issue at many points in your code. You need to fix it everywhere, not just in one of the places.

Comment: There is a lot wrong with this code. `getX` and `setX` return and take `char`, not `char*` or strings. Really, use `std::string`.

Comment: @Synetrix This is also wrong: `char getName()const;` `void setName(char inName);` you'll get only the first character copied into your data members. As already mentioned use `std::string` rather than raw character arrays.

Comment: Literally copy-pasting your title into google yields a bunch of explanations for this, including several answers on this very site. Please do some research before posting.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this;

```
char *x ="bello";
```

should be:

```
const char *x ="bello";
```

the reason is that c++ string literals are of type `const char[]`.

The same applies to (declaration and definition):

```
employee (char *inName,     char *inPosition, double inSalary =0.0);
          ^~~~here consts ~^~
```

Comment: It gives me an error of invalid const char* to char*.

Comment: Same for the signature of the constructor. Also setter signatures (with `char`) are wrong in OPs code. That will be the next things they'll ask you for.